# Concat the results of find

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to concatenate the results of find in Bash. So I got the following code:

```
c="sh -content_image in.jpg, style_image "

find t/Pictures -name "*.jpg"| while read line; do
    c=${c}",",
    c=${c}"$line"
    echo $line

 done

echo $c
```

This first prints all the files in t/Pictures and then the string sh -content_image in.jpg, style_image. While what it's supposed to do is first print all the files and then print that string followed by all of the

So the current output looks like this:

```
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_89.jpg
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_27.jpg
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_47.jpg
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_54.jpg
sh -content_image in.jpg, style_image
```

but I want it too look like

```
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_89.jpg
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_27.jpg
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_47.jpg
t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_54.jpg
sh -content_image in.jpg, style_image t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_89.jpg,t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_27.jpg,t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_47.jpg,t/Pictures/nature/ActiOn_54.jpg
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: thanks to @anubhava I figured it out, also if you are interested as to why this happens you can find more info here https://askubuntu.com/questions/704154/shell-variable-doesnt-change-with-pipe-while-read-combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
c="sh -content_image in.jpg, style_image "

while IFS= read -rd '' line; do
    echo "$line"
    c+="$line,"
done < <(find t/Pictures -name "*.jpg" -print0)

# strip trailing comma
c="${c%,}"
```